# Simulating exposure controls

Tags: three.js

I would like to simulate camera exposure control in my Three.js app, and I'm not sure how I should approach it.

So my question is: how could I implement or simulate exposure control so that I could configure camera or renderer to have a clear image of very darkly lit scenes, or to not overexpose scenes with very bright lights? Ideally it should work as close to how a real camera works (more like adjusting ISO speed rather than aperture/shutter).

Currently I use various configurable EffectComposer postprocessing effects. Some of them allow to control brightness, contrast etc after rendering. Obviously this is no good for other than fine-tuning, because it's not possible to recover blown highlights or black shadows from already rendered standard dynamic range image.

Some approaches that I've considered:

- Hand tuning each light invidually to get desired exposure. This is my current method, which I would like to get rid of.
- Already mentioned postprocessing. This is too limited and results in bad image quality when taken to extremes.
- I see some HDR rendering examples where adjusting exposure is possible. These are implemented with custom HDR shaders, and I would like to use standard Three.js MeshPhongMaterial system and shaders as much as possible because of all the other built-in features like shadows etc etc. I guess it's not easy to use those features AND use some HDR shader approach? Note that I don't need high dynamic range, only adjustable exposure.
- Cheating by applying a some kind of intensity multiplier for all lights in a scene. This seems hard to implement realistically, as the light falloff algorithm etc bring additional complexity which I don't completely understand, and I don't think it's easy to create a result that looks the same as if the camera sensitivity was raised/lowered.
- Simply adjusting gamma in the WebGLRenderer (pre-render). I can't find a way to do this and I'm not totally sure if gamma is the right way to simulate exposure (maybe it is?).

Comment: I see no choice other than to write a custom shader. The existing three.js pipeline is fairly rigid in how it applies lights to a scene, so adjusting their intensity will not likely ever be the result you want. Consider also it's precisely the role of lights and shadows you wish to control.  However, you can build on the existing shaders -- pull all the bits together and change just the final assignment of color. This might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, a custom pipeline, but short of that, how about simply reigning in your specular & emissive towards a nice, median, visible color?
 See picture example of: [False HDR Color Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUQst.jpg).
As for textures, why not run a filter over them? Even just brightness & contrast adjustment might do the trick. This would produce a "universal" HDR-like effect. If you wanted to maintain ordinary lighting at the same time, you might need to maintain two materials for each object.

Comment: Oops, I transposed 'Specular' with 'Emissive' in the picture.